# How to split matrix into two matrices one contains all the integer values and the other float values

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of type double in which some columns are integer values and others are float values as follows

```
X =

a_1  a_2  a_3  a_4
1.0   1    2   2.1
2.2   2    2   3.5
4.1   3    4   4.1
```

I want to split this matrix into two matrices one contains all columns that are integer and the other contains all the columns that are float values. The result should look like

```
x_1 =
 1    2   
 2    2   
 3    4
```

and

```
x_2 = 
1.0   2.1
2.2   3.5
4.1   4.1
```

Is there any built-in function that can do this or any suggestions please

Comment: You don't have separate columns with `integer` and `float` values. All of the values in a matrix of type `double` are of type `double` (or `float`). `1.0` and `1` are the same value so how do you decide which is an `integer` value and which is a `float` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if a number if an integer or not using `round(x)==x`. Using this test you can split your matrix:

```
 int_cols = all( round(x)==x, 1 ); %// logical indexing into integer columns
 x_1 = x(:,int_cols);
 x_2 = x(:,~int_cols);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot very helpful